# How to show python docstring for installed libraries in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pyright

I have sublime text 4, and installed lsp and lsp/pyright for code autocompletion in python, however pyright doesn't show docstring for installed libraries or for python core libraries.

I did my Googling and it seems this is the intended behavior for pyright, so what to do to show docstrings in sublime text? I don't want to use Anaconda plugin by the way.

See also: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-function-method-docstrings-are-not-showing-in-code-completions/68295

**Edit**

Are there any guidelines how to implement this feature myself may be as a sublime package or an extension to pyright?

Comment: How about using `pyls` plugin instead of the Anaconda one?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I installed it now, it shows the docstring for python core libraries(although not nicely formtatted in the popup window) but doesn't show docstring for third-party libraries, e.g. numpy